# Hierarchical Structure

Tags: mysql

Every single user has say, 3 of `GROUP_A`, 10 `GROUP_B`'s per `GROUP_A`, and 20 `GROUP_C`'s per `GROUP_B`. And each of the 20 `GROUP_C`'s involve lots of inserts/deletes...

I'm not an expert, but I've done research but it's all theoretical at this point of course, and I don't have hands on experience with the implementation that's for sure. I *think* my options are something like 'adjacency lists' or 'nested sets'?

Any guidance into the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One way to define your tables:

Users: user_id (primary key), name, etc

Group_A: user_id, group_a_id, group_a_name

Group_B: group_a_id, group_b_id, group_b_name

Group_C: group_b_id, group_c_id, group_c_name

Items: group_c_id, item_id, item_name, details

Comment: This was my initial plan in mind as that would be the intuitive way to go about it, but wouldn't this get too inefficient if there were say a million users or more?

Comment: Even with the 100's of millions of rows you may have across these tables, a moderately good system should be able to handle this (assuming that you can make/use good indices, that the queries won't be too complicated and that you expect a moderate query rate). Simple queries on tables this size should return results in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Interesting! Great to know :) I'll go do research into indices because it's been a while since I last studied about them! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You should post more info on your exact requirements.

Just theoretical, you can use 3 tables:

```
[users]
-------
user_id
user_name

[groups]
--------
group_id
group_parent_id
group_name

[users_groups_data]
-----------------
user_id
group_id
info_data
```

From your request, the data you're looking to store looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
user_id, group-A-ID-1, info
user_id, group-A-ID-2, info
user_id, group-A-ID-3, info
user_id, group-A-ID-1, group-B-ID-1, info
...
user_id, group-A-ID-1, group-B-ID-1, group-C-ID-1, info
...
user_id, group-A-ID-1, group-B-ID-1, group-C-ID-20, info
...
user_id, group-A-ID-1, group-B-ID-10, info
```

Because your hierarchy models is Group A -> Group B -> Group C, it's enough to store in [user_groups_data] table just the user_id, the last group id (in the groups hierarchy tree), and the info

So, data in the tables can look like:

```
[users]
-------
1 | Mihai
2 | Lucian

[groups]
------------------
1 | NULL | Group A-1
2 | 1    | Group B-1
3 | 1    | Group B-2
4 | 2    | Group C-1

[users_groups_data]
-------------------
1 | 1 | "Mihai's data, for group A-1"
1 | 2 | "Mihai's data, for group B-1, for group A-1"
1 | 4 | "Mihai's data, for group C-1, for group B-1, for group A-1"
```

This can and will work (theoretically :) ...), but you will need a recursive function (in application or in the database) that can return the parent group id (ex. B-1), or the top group id (ex. A-1) for any group id value given as an input parameter (C-1).

But ... like I said: The more info you give, the better responses you get.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Basically there's 3 Group_A's which are 'containers' to each hold 10 or so Group_B's, and each of the Group_B's are again containers but they hold 20 or so Group_C's which change independently rather frequently(like on a day to day basis for each user). And every Group_X and the data stored in the Group is unique, to every user. 
So every item for Group_C is different for User_A than it is for User_B because User_B will have his/her own set of Group_C items. Same goes with Group_B and Group_A's for every single user...Hope that makes sense?